# Image Roll Over (Instagram Feed webapp)

Tags: css

I've built an app (using the instagram API) which pulls instagram images into a webapp. I've been working on some CSS code which displays a roll over of a large heart  upon hover (which will eventually show the number of "likes" the image has received).

My question is - how to make the heart an overlay on the instagram so that the outline of the instagram image is still visible behind the heart shape upon hover?

Any help is super appreciated! Thanks.

```
<DIV class="roll">
<IMG class="on"  src="http://f.cl.ly/items/3s0M340B2I0a171l0H1o/testinstagram_image2.jpg">
<IMG class="off" src="http://f.cl.ly/items/321322043C0Y2g0R2K0g/smallerheart.jpg">
</DIV>


<STYLE type="text/css">
.roll {width: 360px;}
.roll {height: 330px;}
.roll {background: blue;}
.roll .on { dislay: block; }
.roll .off { display: none; }
.roll:hover .on { display: none; }
.roll:hover .off { display: block; }
</STYLE>
```

Comment: You mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DuTBd/1/

Comment: Nope, I mean without any whitespace (ie only the heart is on the image). Thanks!

Comment: You have to make the heart image as png with only heart icon. then use what I have done in fiddle. 
Currently, your heart image contains white space

Comment: Okay so to clarify, if I use your code but make the heart.jpg into a png (without whitespace) it should work? There's nothing more I need to do? Thanks so much again!!

Comment: z-index allows you to stack an element in order. or you can say one behind the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.roll {width: 360px;}
.roll {height: 330px;}
.roll {background: blue;}
.roll .on { dislay: block; }
.roll .off { display: none; }
.roll:hover .off { z-index: 0;position:absolute; top:25px; left: 8px; display: block; }
.roll:hover .on {z-index: 10; display: block; }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DuTBd/1)